# OpenCV C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, opencv, feature-detection, surf

I am trying to use SURF but I am having trouble finding way to do so in C. The documentation only seems to have stuff for C++ in terms of.

I have been able to detect SURF feature:

```
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("img5.jpg");

    CvMat* image = cvCreateMat(img->height, img->width, CV_8UC1);
    cvCvtColor(img, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // detecting keypoints
    CvSeq *imageKeypoints = 0, *imageDescriptors = 0;
    int i;

    //Extract SURF points by initializing parameters
    CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(1, 1);
    cvExtractSURF( image, 0, &imageKeypoints, &imageDescriptors, storage, params );
    printf("Image Descriptors: %d\n", imageDescriptors->total);

    //draw the keypoints on the captured frame
    for( i = 0; i < imageKeypoints->total; i++ )
    {
        CvSURFPoint* r = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( imageKeypoints, i );
        CvPoint center;
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound(r->pt.x);
        center.y = cvRound(r->pt.y);
        radius = cvRound(r->size*1.2/9.*2);
        cvCircle( image, center, radius, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, 8, 0 );
    }
```

But I can't find the method that I need to compare the descriptors of 2 images. I found this code in C++ but I'm having trouble translating it:

```
    // matching descriptors
    BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> > matcher;
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

    // drawing the results
    namedWindow("matches", 1);
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, img_matches);
    imshow("matches", img_matches);
    waitKey(0);
```

I would appreciate if someone could lead me on to a descriptor matcher or even better, let me know where I can find the OpenCV documentation in C only.

Answer (score 0):

This link might give you a hint. https://projects.developer.nokia.com/opencv/browser/opencv/opencv-2.3.1/samples/c/find_obj.cpp . Look in the function `naiveNearestNeighbor`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the blog post from [thioldhack](http://thisoldhack.blogspot.com/2010/11/opencv-surf-and-qt.html). Contains a sample code. Its for QT, but you can easily do it for VC++ or any other. You will need to match the Key points using K-nearest neighbour algorithm. It has all.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The slightly longer but surest way is to compile OpenCV on your computer with debug information and just to step into the C++ implementation with a debugger. You can also copy it aside to your project and start peeling it like an onion till you get to pure C.